# diferenciar tipo de usuário com php

Tags: php, mysqli

Tenho um sistema de cadastro do meu sistema que tem dois tipos de usuários: professor e aluno. tem um campo no formulário que é o "tipo de usuário" do qual pode ser professor ou aluno. Eu fiz um código, mas está muito feio e queria que me ajudassem. Ele funciona, mas eu queria saber se tem como fazer de uma forma diferente e mais simples. se for aluno tem que mandar para uma página e professor manda para outra. segue o código:

```
<?php
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
    error_reporting(E_ALL);

    session_start();
    include_once "conecta.php";

    if(isset($_POST)){
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $senha = $_POST['senha'];

        if(isset($conexao)){
            $stmt = mysqli_prepare($conexao,"select email from aluno where email = ? and senha = ?");
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ss", $email, $senha);

            mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

            mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $resultado);
            mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt);

            if(isset($resultado) > 0){
                $_SESSION['login'] = $email;
                $_SESSION['tipousuario'] = "aluno";
                header("Location: control/home.php");
            }else{
                echo "Usuário ou senha incorretos";
                header("Location: index.php");
            }
        }

        if(isset($conexao)){
            $stmt = mysqli_prepare($conexao, "select email from professor where email = ? and senha = ?");
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ss", $email, $senha);

            mysqli_execute($stmt);

            mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $resultado);
            mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt);

            if(isset($resultado) > 0){
                $_SESSION['login'] = $email;
                $_SESSION['tipousuario'] = "professor";
                header("Location: control/home2.php");
            }else{
                echo "Usuário ou senha incorretos";
                header("Location: index.php");
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acredito que ao invés de `echo "Usuário ou senha incorretos";` tu poderia passar a mensagem de erro de acesso para a index por parâmetro, para apresentar ao usuário.
Também tentaria extrair uns métodos/isolar um pouco as coisas em [funções php](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/functions.user-defined.php) para deixar o teu código mais legível e facilitar a manutenção, por exemplo, isolando verificação de professor e aluno(não testado):

```
<?php
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
    error_reporting(E_ALL);

    session_start();
    include_once "conecta.php";

    if(isset($_POST)){
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $senha = $_POST['senha'];
        $_SESSION['login'] = $email;

        if(isAluno($conexao,$email,$senha)){

            $_SESSION['tipousuario'] = "aluno";
            header("Location: control/home.php");

        }else if(isProfessor($conexao,$email,$senha)){

            $_SESSION['tipousuario'] = "professor";
            header("Location: control/home2.php");

        }else{
            header("Location: index.php?msg=Usuário ou senha incorretos");
        }


    }

        /**
     Função para verificar se é professor
     */
    function isProfessor($conexao,$email, $senha){
        $retorno=false;
        if(isset($conexao)){
            $stmt = mysqli_prepare($conexao,"select email from professor where email = ? and senha = ?");
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ss", $email, $senha);
            mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
            mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $resultado);
            mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt);

            if(isset($resultado) > 0){$retorno=true;}
        }
        return $retorno;
    }
    /**
     Função para verificar se é aluno
     */
    function isAluno($conexao,$email, $senha){
        $retorno=false;
        if(isset($conexao)){
            $stmt = mysqli_prepare($conexao,"select email from aluno where email = ? and senha = ?");
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ss", $email, $senha);
            mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
            mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $resultado);
            mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt);

            if(isset($resultado) > 0){$retorno=true;}
        }
            return $retorno;
    }
?>
```

Ainda, caso existam muitas funções neste arquivo, talvez prefira criar uma [CLASSE php](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.oop5.basic.php) que contenha essas funções para serem reutilizadas.

Answer (score 1):

Não tem muito que simplificar não mas dei uma reorganizada no seu código

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

session_start();
include_once "conecta.php";

if(isset($_POST)){
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $senha = $_POST['senha'];

    if(isset($conexao)){
        $stmt = mysqli_prepare($conexao,"select email from aluno where email = ? and senha = ?");
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ss", $email, $senha);

        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

        mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $resultado);
        mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt);

        if(isset($resultado) > 0){
            $_SESSION['login'] = $email;
            $_SESSION['tipousuario'] = "aluno";
            header("Location: control/home.php");
         }else{
            $stmt = mysqli_prepare($conexao, "select email from professor where email = ? and senha = ?");
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ss", $email, $senha);

            mysqli_execute($stmt);

            mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $resultado);
            mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt);

            if(isset($resultado) > 0){
               $_SESSION['login'] = $email;
               $_SESSION['tipousuario'] = "professor";
               header("Location: control/home2.php");
            }else{
               echo "Usuário ou senha incorretos";
               header("Location: index.php");
            }           

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Na verdade vc resolveria isso no primeiro If! Se a $_SESSION['tipousuario'] for diferente de "aluno" rode o select na tabela professor e direcione para a pagina do professor do contrário direcione para a do aluno!